# insert data into a table from another table, while sorting according to a field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am making attendance management system in VS2010 with RFID technology, doing all my backend data manipulation in SQL server 2005, I know basic SQL, but I'm going to need some help with this this issue.

I have the following tables:

facultymasterdata

```
fname
fid
dept
title
phone
dob
```

timings

```
fname
fid
intime_a
outtime_d
lunchout_b
lunchin_c
```

rawdumps

```
fid
timecode
currtime
```

data here is saved from a serial port data logger program I wrote in vb.net, fid being the RFID tag ID, timecode being A,B,C or D (for identifying time as intime-A, lunchout-B, lunchin-C, outtime-D) and currtime is the current system time. I get the RFID tag IDs via a microcontroller that adds the time code according to physical button presses.

What I need to do is sort the all the data from `rawdumps` and copy it into `timings` according to the timecode. The `fid` and `currtime` fields in `rawdumps` which have time code as "A" get saved into the field `intime_a` in timings. AND also the `fname` from `facultymasterdata` corresponding to the `fid`.

Any help of info will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It makes no sense to sort the rows that you are inserting. Once they are in the target table they are unsorted, because rows in a relational database are **not sorted**. You will have to sort them when you *retrieve* them from the target table.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name, What I intended to have as my final data was the table timings, with fname from the the masterdata table, the fid from rawdumps, along with that person's timings (sorted from rawdata).
Think of it this way, just 1 person has logged his times, and in raw data, I have 4 rows, with 4 different times, with respective timecodes A,B,C and D. Now I want to sort the times in each of the 4 rows, into the table timings, so that the time next to A is under the field intime_a and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, someone helped me out, what I needed to do was convert a column into rows while sorting it. I needed to use cross tabs.

This is what I needed to do:

```
SELECT F.fName, F.fID, 
MIN(CASE WHEN R.TimeCode = 'A' THEN CurrTime END) AS Intime_a,
MAX(CASE WHEN R.TimeCode = 'D' THEN CurrTime END) AS outtime_d,
MIN(CASE WHEN R.TimeCode = 'B' THEN CurrTime END) AS LunchOut_b,
MAX(CASE WHEN R.TimeCode = 'C' THEN CurrTime END) AS LunchIn_c
FROM dbo.facultymasterdata F LEFT JOIN dbo.rawdumps R ON F.fid = R.fid 
GROUP BY F.fid, F.fname
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean with the [fid] and [curtime] fields have code "A" and gets saved in [intime_a]. Is this a sum?

This should get you on the right tracks.

```
INSERT INTO timings(fname,fid,intime_a)
    SELECT a.fname, b.fid, b.curtime
    FROM facultymasterdata a, rawdumps b 
    WHERE a.fid = b.fid
    ORDER BY b.timecode;
```

EDIT: after reading your edit of the question and response in comment, I'd write a trigger to handle this insert.

Comment: The timecode is a field according to which I need to sort my data, the data in that field is either A,B,C or D.
If its A, I need the currtime form rawdata to be placed into the field intime_a in the table timings. Similarly if its B, then the currtime should be placed in the fieldunder lunchout_b.

Comment: Column names should not be enclosed in single quotes. Single quotes denote character literals

Comment: You're right a_horse_with_no_name. I ment ` instead of ' so edited the post :) thanks for the heads-up

Comment: Backticks are not valid for SQL Server either ;) (and they are non-standard and not required for those names anyway)

Comment: I'm used to mysql nowadays and backticks are their way to quote columns to be able to use funky table names. totally missed the sql-server as I was looking at the tags. Well played sir :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably make use of a union select, resulting in a big nasty insert like this

```
insert into timings
(fname,fid,intime_a,lunchout_b,lunchin_c, outtime_d)
select
    f.fname,
    f.fid,
    r.intime_a,
    r.lunchout_b,
    r.lunchin_c,
    r.outtime_d,
from
    facultymasterdata as f
inner join (
    select
        fid as fid,
        currtime as currtime,
        currtime as intime_a,
        null as lunchout_b,
        null as lunchin_c,
        null as outtime_d,
    from
        rawdumps
    where timecode = 'A'
    union select
        fid as fid,
        currtime as currtime,
        null as intime_a,
        currtime as lunchout_b,
        null as lunchin_c,
        null as outtime_d,
    from
        rawdumps
    where timecode = 'B'
    union select
        fid as fid,
        currtime as currtime,
        null as intime_a,
        null as lunchout_b,
        currtime as lunchin_c,
        null as outtime_d,
    from
        rawdumps
    where timecode = 'C'
    union select
        fid as fid,
        currtime as currtime,
        null as intime_a,
        null as lunchout_b,
        null as lunchin_c,
        currtime as outtime_d,
    from
        rawdumps
    where timecode = 'D'
    ) r on r.fid = f.fid
order by r.currtime
```